# Colorize log4j logs in eclipse and netbeans console

Tags: eclipse, logging, netbeans, console, log4j

Wanting to colorize the log4j output to make our massive logs easier to read, within an IDE.

I need something that works on Eclipse AND Netbeans. Hoping to do this within log4j or by appending something to log4j.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the colouring console in eclipse , you can use the plug-ins [logviewer](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/logviewer/) or [Grep Console](http://marian.musgit.com/projects_grepconsole.php)

[image]

For the netbean , you can vote this feature to be released in next release at [here](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=195924)